# Spring Data JPA FindBy methods not working

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I got some error with my code. I'm trying to use MongoDB and MYSQL both on one same project. For this point, I think I'm good but my JPARepository kinda give me some headaches this last hours. The fact is that I can't implement findBy*** methods. Here is my code and the errors:

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface AppUserRepository extends JpaRepository<AppUser,Long> {
    AppUser findByUsername(String username);
    AppUser findByEmail(String email);
}
```

Class

```
@Entity
public class AppUser {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;
    private String password;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;
    private boolean enabled;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<AppRole> roles = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private VerificationToken verificationToken;


    public AppUser() {
        this.enabled = false;
    }

    public AppUser(Long id, String username, String password, Collection<AppRole> roles,String email) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.roles = roles;
        this.email = email;
        this.enabled = false;
    }


    public AppUser(String username, String password, Collection<AppRole> roles, String email) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.roles = roles;
        this.email = email;
        this.enabled = false;
    }

    public VerificationToken getVerificationToken() {
        return verificationToken;
    }

    public void setVerificationToken(VerificationToken verificationToken) {
        this.verificationToken = verificationToken;
    }


    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return this.enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @JsonSetter
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Collection<AppRole> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Collection<AppRole> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}
```

Application class

```
@SpringBootApplication()
@EnableAutoConfiguration()
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "com.anne.juliette.pharma.entities"})
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackageClasses = {OrderRepository.class, PhotoRepository.class})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = {AppRoleRepository.class, AppUserRepository.class, VerificationTokenRepository.class})
public class PharmaApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder getBCPE(){ return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();}

    @Autowired
    private AccountService accountService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PharmaApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> simpleCorsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("http://localhost:4200"));
        config.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        config.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> bean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        accountService.saveRole(new AppRole(null,"ADMIN"));
        accountService.saveRole(new AppRole(null,"USER"));

        AppUser user1 = new AppUser("admin","1234",null, "admin@admin.com");
        AppUser user2 = new AppUser("user","1234",null, "user@admin.com");
        user1.setEnabled(true);
        user2.setEnabled(true);
        accountService.saveUser(user1);
        accountService.saveUser(user2);
        accountService.addRoleToUser("admin@admin.com","ADMIN");
        accountService.addRoleToUser("admin@admin.com","USER");
        accountService.addRoleToUser("user@admin.com","USER");

        System.out.println(accountService.allUsers());
    }
}
```

AccountService class

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class AccountServiceImpl implements AccountService {

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private AppUserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private AppRoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Autowired
    private VerificationTokenService verificationTokenService;

    @Override
    public AppUser saveUser(AppUser user) {
        String hashPass = bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword());
        user.setPassword(hashPass);
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public AppRole saveRole(AppRole role) {
        return roleRepository.save(role);
    }

    @Override
    public void addRoleToUser(String email, String roleName) {
        AppRole role = roleRepository.findByRole(roleName);
        AppUser user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
        if(user.getRoles() == null){
        List<AppRole> list = new ArrayList<AppRole>();
        list.add(role);
        user.setRoles(list);
        } else {
            user.getRoles().add(role);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public AppUser findUserByUsername(String username) {  return userRepository.findByUsername(username);    }

    @Override
    public AppUser findUserByEmail(String email){   return userRepository.findByEmail(email);    }

    @Override
    public List<AppUser> allUsers() {   return userRepository.findAll();    }

    @Override
    public boolean emailExist(String email) {
        return userRepository.findByEmail(email) != null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean usernameExist(String username) {
        return userRepository.findByUsername(username) != null;
    }


}
```

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Cannot create binding for parameter reference [org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.expression.JpaCriteriaParameter@66716959] - reference is not a parameter of this query; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot create binding for parameter reference [org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.expression.JpaCriteriaParameter@66716959] - reference is not a parameter of this query
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:374) ~[spring-orm-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:257) ~[spring-orm-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528) ~[spring-orm-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153) ~[spring-tx-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy91.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.anne.juliette.pharma.services.AccountServiceImpl.allUsers(AccountServiceImpl.java:65) ~[main/:na]
    at com.anne.juliette.pharma.services.AccountServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$4e5d1390.invoke(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366) ~[spring-tx-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.anne.juliette.pharma.services.AccountServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$55c904fc.allUsers(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at com.anne.juliette.pharma.PharmaApplication.run(PharmaApplication.java:77) [main/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:795) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot create binding for parameter reference [org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.expression.JpaCriteriaParameter@66716959] - reference is not a parameter of this query
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingsImpl.makeBinding(QueryParameterBindingsImpl.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-6.0.0.Alpha5.jar:6.0.0.Alpha5]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingsImpl.getBinding(QueryParameterBindingsImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-6.0.0.Alpha5.jar:6.0.0.Alpha5]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.SqmUtil.createJdbcParameterBindings(SqmUtil.java:173) ~[hibernate-core-6.0.0.Alpha5.jar:6.0.0.Alpha5]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.performList(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:155) ~[hibernate-core-6.0.0.Alpha5.jar:6.0.0.Alpha5]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.doList(QuerySqmImpl.java:437) ~[hibernate-core-6.0.0.Alpha5.jar:6.0.0.Alpha5]
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractQuery.list(AbstractQuery.java:1356) ~[hibernate-core-6.0.0.Alpha5.jar:6.0.0.Alpha5]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:136) ~[hibernate-core-6.0.0.Alpha5.jar:6.0.0.Alpha5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:355) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:78) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.ImplementationInvocationMetadata.invoke(ImplementationInvocationMetadata.java:72) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:382) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:205) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:549) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:155) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:130) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366) ~[spring-tx-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Can you also post the AccountService class?

Comment: Hi Ehab, thanks for your answer and yes of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Hibernate 6.0.0.Alpha5, which is an alpha version, far from production ready and might contain errors like this. Try the latest stable version which is 5.4.16.Final as of today.

Comment: I got this error with hibernate-core-6.2.1.Final.jar. Happens randomly when binding Longs of an in clause